# Update related entities ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: ef-code-first, aspnetboilerplate

I just started using ASP.NET Boilerplate and what i want to do is to update an entity and its related entity automatically. For example, when i'm updating the Person entity i would want the Address to be also updated. Here is how i defined the entities:

```
public class Person : FullAuditedEntity<long>, IMayHaveTenant, IPassivable
{
    public const int MaxFirstNameLength = 256;
    public const int MaxLastNameLength = 256;

    [MaxLength(MaxFirstNameLength)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(MaxLastNameLength)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int? TenantId { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        CreationTime = Clock.Now;
    }
}

public class Address : FullAuditedEntity<long>, IMayHaveTenant, IPassivable
{
    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    public string Street2 { get; set; }
    public virtual long? PersonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int? TenantId { get; set; }

    public Address()
    {
        CreationTime = Clock.Now;
    }
}
```

Do you know how i can achieve that using the current implementation of this framework?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I got the same issue with you, please tell me if you have the solution? Thanks

Comment: Your question seems a bit vague so sorry if i'm not understanding correctly. However, if I need to update connected entities at the same time I inject both repositories inside the same service, and create a method that updates both of them given whatever data you passed.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you need to re-model this as you have a `Address->Person` and a `Person->Address`.  That would not be easy to deal with.

If it was me I would simply have a Address Property on the Person ie Person.Address and use the foreign key attrib.  The FK Att will mean that saving the Person with a changed Address will also track the Address change and save it  automatically for you.

If a single address can be associated with > 1 Person then you could also optionally add a navigation property on the Address class so that you can move to all the Persons associated with a single Adress eg `Address.Persons`

if you do not use the foreign key attribute, it is treated as an independent association - so handled as separate object in state manager / change tracker.

Comment: Thank you for your input. i am still not able to update the information in the database. I am still searching in the framework something able to enable/disable tracking related entities, maybe.